# Link returns undefined when mapping array to JSX component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, gatsby

**The following code gives an error when I visit the page this component is rendered on:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import SEO from '../components/seo'

import {
  Divider,
  Card,
  Link,
} from '@blueprintjs/core'
 

const TagPage = ({ pageContext }) => {
  const { name, description, tagsCount, questions, } = pageContext

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title={name} description={description} />
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>{description}</p>
      <Divider />
      <br/><br/>

      {questions.map((q) => {
        return (
        <>
          <Link 
            to={`tagsQuestion-${q.id}`} 
            style={{
              color: `inherit`,
              textDecoration: `none`,
            }}
          >
            <Card interactive='true'>
              <p>{q.id}</p>
              <p>{q.prompt}</p>
              
            </Card>
          </Link>
          <br/>
        </>
      )
      })}
      
    </Layout>
  )
}
  
export default TagPage
```

However if I change:

```
<Link to={`/question/${q.id}`}>...</Link>
```

into

```
<a href={`/question/${q.id}`} >...</a>
```

then the page will render and be useable without any errors.

This is the current error message I am getting:

```
(AppContainer, in main (at layout.js:33)) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `TagPage
```

**Question:**

Why can I not use the [Link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/) component in this situation?

**Info:**

`questions` is an array
TagPage is a page created in `gatsby-node.js`

Thanks you, for your time, feel free to ask questions as needed.

Comment: Can you update question to include `layout.js` and the components listed in the error?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I updated the main code segment to contain the entire file `tagPage.js`

Comment: `AppContainer` component and `layout.js` file. If that is the code you posted then you should mention that as it isn't clear by the names. What `Link` are you trying to use? You import one from `'@blueprintjs/core'`, but linked to a Gatsby link component doc.

Comment: You are awesome man, you solved my problem. Not sure this "bug" is worthy of Stack Overflow though. Thank you very much for the help! Feel free to post an answer, I will gladly give you credit.

Comment: Let's chalk it up to a typo. :)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
import {
  Divider,
  Card,
  Link,
} from '@blueprintjs/core'
```

with

```
import { Link } from 'gatsby'
import {
  Divider,
  Card,
} from '@blueprintjs/core'
```